# iOS_Charts HorizontalBarChartView Vertical scrolling

Tags: swift, ios-charts

What changes need to be done if I have to make 'HorizontalBarChartView' vertically scrollable. 
I want to show maximum of 8 bars at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It already supports so. you can set maxScaleX/Y to limit the scale,

also you can try `setVisibleYRangeMaximum`. horizontal bar chart's x axis is the same as normal bar's x axis position. It's not reverted with y axis

Comment: If i set setVisibleYRangeMaximum = 100 then the bar size will be proper. Also I am setting chartDataSet.barSpace = 0.4, since the data I am giving to chart is dynamic if I have less data the width of the bar is increases and if the data is more the width of the bar decreases. Is there any way how I can maintain constant barwidth?

Comment: no. the bar space is in percentage calculation. not fixed pixel value. but you can write your own logic

Comment: How to show vertical scroll indicator in Horizontal Bar chart. I won't find any variable or function to show/ enable vertical scroll indicator. If some one know please let me know.

Comment: @PareshKarnawat it is not a scroll view

Comment: is there any way to show the Horizontal or Vertical Indicator?